# Docker Swarm, Compose and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm attempting to run a containerized application that relies on a postgres database. I am using Swarm and docker-compose to manage it.

I manually create a volume against a host that is part of the Swarm cluster ( `docker volume create --name=my_data` ) and use this volume in my compose file. I say in the compose file that the volume is external.

I find that when the container starts the data volume and the postgres application are not necessarily co-located. If they are *not* co-located, docker seems to create me a new volume.

A little further reading has lead me to believe that I should be looking at volume plugins such as Flocker. If I want to achieve persistent data for swarm applications using a database, is it best practice to use a volume plugin like this?

My compose file ...

```
version: '2'
services:
   ui:
      image : ui
      ports:
       - 8080:8080
      environment:
       ADDRESS_SERVICE_URI: http://camel:8091
   camel:
      image : camel
      ports:
       - 18081:8081
       - 18091:8091
      expose:
       - 8081
       - 8091
   postgresql:
      image: postgres:9.4.5
      volumes:
       - app1_address_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
   app1_address_data:
      external: true

networks:
   default:
     external:
       name: my-net
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://blog.emccode.com/2015/11/03/use-docker-swarm-with-a-data-persistence-layer/

Comment: You got it, need to use some kind of volume plugin that will automagically move your volumes around and make them available across hosts.